# Сохранить данные с формы в БД. JavaEE

Tags: mysql, java-ee, form, servlet

У меня имеется форма с

1. `<input name="name">`
2. `<select name="type"> <option val=1>.......`
3. `<input name="latitude">`
4. `<input name="longitude">`

При нажатии на кнопку `submit` методом `POST` отправятся такие параметры как:

`name, type, latitude, longitude`

Вот и сам код сервлета:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //getting parameters
    String pointName = request.getParameter("name");

    String STRpointType = request.getParameter("type");
    int pointType = Integer.parseInt(STRpointType);

    String lat = request.getParameter("latitude");
    String lng = request.getParameter("longitude");

    String query = "INSERT INTO joker.point (name, type_id, lat, lng) VALUES (" + pointName + "," + pointType + "," + lat + "," + lng + ");";

    Connection connection;
    Statement statement;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/joker";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(query);
    } catch (SQLException |ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    request.setAttribute("point_name", pointName);
    request.setAttribute("point_type", pointType);
    request.setAttribute("point_lat", lat);
    request.setAttribute("point_lng", lng);


    String page;
    try {
        page = request.getParameter("page");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        page = "error";
    }
    if (page != null) {
        switch (page) {
            case "point_added":
                RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin_point_added.jsp");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                rd.include(request, response);
                break;
            default:
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin_point_error.jsp").forward(request, response);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Я нажимаю на кнопку у меня перебрасывает на страничку с тем что `point added` но в базе данных нет тех данных которые я взял с формы...

Что я делаю не так? Где у меня ошибка?  но в `<form action="/sqlquery" method=POST>` прописал..

Comment: Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой, НО у меня возникали сложности из-за того, что в POST форме присутствовал параметр enctype <form method="post" action="InsertTo" enctype="multipart/form-data">, приложи код формы.

Comment: У меня нету в форме `enctype`, то есть мне его нужно добавить?

Comment: Нет добавлять его как раз не нужно.

Comment: @drno в форме у меня я не думаю есть какие-то проблемы, мне кажется в сервлете я допускаю какую-то ошибку, только вот не знаю какую..(

Comment: получилось решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас все верно, кроме запроса который вы отправляете, там в синтаксисе ошибка есть:

```
//Ваш запрос
String query = "INSERT INTO joker.point (name, type_id, lat, lng) VALUES (" + pointName + "," + pointType + "," + lat + "," + lng + ");";
```

Поменяйте на вот этот который снизу, и сравните:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO joker.point (name, type_id, lat, lng) VALUES ('"+pointName+ "','"+pointType+"','"+lat+ "','"+lng+"')";
```

Общий код вашего сервлета сохраняющий данные в БД, будет выглядеть вот так:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //getting parameters
        String pointName = request.getParameter("name");

        String STRpointType = request.getParameter("type");
        int pointType = Integer.parseInt(STRpointType);
        String lat = request.getParameter("latitude");
        String lng = request.getParameter("longitude");
        String query = "INSERT INTO joker.point (name, type_id, lat, lng) VALUES ('"+pointName+ "','"+pointType+"','"+lat+ "','"+lng+"')";

        Connection connection;
        Statement statement;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/joker";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "password";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute(query);
        } catch (SQLException |ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        request.setAttribute("point_name", pointName);
        request.setAttribute("point_type", pointType);
        request.setAttribute("point_lat", lat);
        request.setAttribute("point_lng", lng);


        String page;
        try {
            page = request.getParameter("page");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            page = "error";
        }
        if (page != null) {
            switch (page) {
                case "point_added":
                    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin_point_added.jsp");
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    rd.include(request, response);
                    break;
                default:
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin_point_error.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Неа, не помогло.. Снова так же

Comment: String SQLquery = "INSERT INTO joker.point (name, coord, type_id) VALUES ('"+pointName+
    "','"+coord+"',"+pointType+")"; - poitname у тебя string, а значение не в кавычках и плюс ; нужно убрать из текста INSERT

Comment: какого текста? Не понял..

Comment: поменяй вот эту строку - String SQLquery = "INSERT INTO joker.point (name, coord, type_id) VALUES ('"+pointName+
    "','"+coord+"',"+pointType+")";

Comment: дадададада!!!)))))))) Я понял теперь свою ошибку) Спасибо тебе) Ух ты, я не мог в этом разобраться целую неделю, решил уже сюда обратиться) Спасибо)

Comment: ща я немного поменяю твой ответ) так как немного поменял сервлет)